# Postgres CTE execution guarantees, inlining

Tags: postgresql, sql-standard

Following query with non deterministic function yields two same rows - the CTE is computed and re-used.

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT uuid_generate_v4() AS id)
SELECT id FROM foo
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM foo

| id 
| 741f4f69-416b-4b4c-9226-559527f4a84e
| 741f4f69-416b-4b4c-9226-559527f4a84e
```

Is this execution guaranteed? Can postgres decide to inline it to

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT uuid_generate_v4() AS id) t
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM (SELECT uuid_generate_v4() AS id) t

| id 
| 262f0006-b4d5-440a-a86a-d79cd2684458
| c24b5835-9c5c-4d6f-b649-8e510129015b
```

which yields two different ids (and thus different result)?

What does the SQL standard specify? Does Postgres provide any additional guarantees? If it's not guaranteed, what is standard way to reuse statement that depends on non deterministic procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL standard does not define behaviour in such cases, leaving it to the implementation of SQL servers. It [(2013 draft anyway)](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2301-2350/32N2311T-text_for_ballot-CD_9075-2.pdf) says, in particular, in section **7.6 <table reference>**

> 25) A <query name> is possibly non-deterministic if the <query expression> identified by the <query name> is possibly non-deterministic.

where <query name> is what is defined by the `WITH` clause, while in **4.22 Determinism** it mentions:

> Recognizing that an operation is deterministic is a difficult task, it is in general not mandated by this International Standard.[...] For other operations, this International Standard does not label an operation as deterministic; instead it identifies certain operations as “possibly non-deterministic”. Specific definitions can be found in other subclauses relative to <value expression>, <table reference>, <table primary>, <query specification>, <query expression>, and <SQL procedure statement>.

Section **4.15.8 Syntactic analysis of derived tables and cursors** can be interpreted to mean that each reference to `uuid_generate_v4()` in your case will produce a distinct node on the syntax tree. Whether the optimizer of a particular DBMS chooses to honour its non-deterministic nature and execute the function twice is implementation-specific though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this execution guaranteed . Postgres will not inline it in the way you mentioned.

> A useful property of WITH queries is that they are evaluated only once
>   per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
>   than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries. Thus, expensive
>   calculations that are needed in multiple places can be placed within a
>   WITH query to avoid redundant work. Another possible application is to
>   prevent unwanted multiple evaluations of functions with side-effects.
>    (from [Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: Do you know if its sql standard or postgres specific?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ANSI SQL 99 to give a definitive answer. Quickly going through it (http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf) , I can tell it specifies what is visible, and what elements WITH clause (recursive and non-recursive) may contain rather than particular execution order. I assume it's implementation details (even though most likely other RDBMS behave similar to Postgres in such cases)